# this$store function is undefined

Tags: axios, vuex, store

I am trying to use vuex's store to make some API calls but after installing vuex, importing store to my files and following other stack overflow answers, like making sure vuex is installed, if i am exporting my store file with " Vuex.Store" and etc but my loadCalls function is still not working.

This is the error i get:

```
this.$store.loadCalls is not a function
```

Here is my function and how i am trying to call it, it is declared in my ACTIONS section of my store.js file.

```
loadCalls() {
   axios
        .get("/some/calls")
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        });
},
```

I try using it in my `beforeMount()` when my component loads:

```
beforeMount(){
    this.$store.loadCalls();
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe, you forgot to include the store inside the Vue instance. Where is the  `import store from './store'` ?

Comment: In my main.js file. I also defined it here: 
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use `vm.$nextTick` inside of mounted: See: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: Is `loadCalls` defined in the `actions` section of your store?

Comment: yes, it is in my actions section ins my store file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you defined an action like this:

```js
actions: {
  loadCalls() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('loadCalls');
```

Actions aren't exposed directly, you call them using `dispatch`.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Comment: Nice! Thanks mate, it was big help.

Comment: i do have one more question though. this calls gives me a bigass array. how do i save that in a state and use it in other components?